# SFMC Mobile Push Inbox Message Interaction displays a different URL once delivered

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I am trying to send out a mobile push inbox message sent as interaction using a URL populated via an ampscript variable.

Once the inbox message is sent the URL does not work, we have notices the URL is changed.

I run the test using an hardcoded URL, as I understand with cloud pages SFMC will encrypt the URL. However, even using the hardcoded URL (https://cloudpage1.com?qs=124354364364) once the inbox message is delivered the URL changes (https://cloudpage1.com?qs=124354362222)the page frame is loaded but because it changes the URL it loses all the parameters and the page is not customised with the copy for the client.

has anyone experienced anything like this before?

We tried the same thing with push notifications and the URL works fine. The problem is just related to the inbox message.

Comment: Open a case through your support representative.

Comment: Yes we have done this - so far they have not been very helpful

Comment: If support cannot solve your problem then ask them to escalate the issue to the Mobile Push team.  They should create an investigation for the MP team without hesitation.

Answer (score 1):

Solution recommended by support was to add a custom variable via the admin section.
Setup > Feature Settings > MobilePush > Select your app settings

Custom Keys: Enable and add a new key
[image]

These keys are used to extend the mobile app using the custom key and value pairs. Configure key values when you create the message.
These custom keys field will appear and support ampscript.

The custom key field appears under the select cloud page section in the inbox message (interaction type).

As part of the process select a landing page and replace the link populated by SFMC with your URL variable %%=v(@URL2)=%%
use the same variable in the CK section %%=v(@URL2)=%%

The %%=v(@URL2)=%% value is retrieved from the data extension used to dynamically populate the content of the inbox message.

The mobile developer team can now use this variable to retrieve the URL and avoid caching from push notification to inbox message.

Comment: What do you mean by message and custom key. Is it the URL you are adding both in custom key and AMPS script

Comment: We defined the push message variables in a data extension. Eg the url would be built via ampscript in the DE however would only be picked up by the push message. Enabling a new custom key you can define the variable for the url where you select the landing page redirect and in the custom key and then it works. The mobile team had to also reference the new custom key.

Comment: In the sentence "Place your inbox message URL variable in both the message and custom key" . Where are you placing your URL variable in message? Can you explain more elaborately?  Or any reference to documentation

Comment: @MacDeveloper I cannot access an active app and therefore cannot take a screenshot of it, I hope the edits help